# iPhone - Loading ActivityIndicator

Tags: iphone, animation, android-activity, uiactivityindicatorview

I am aware of my problem but cannot find a solution.  When the button is pressed it tells the UIActivityIndicatorView to startAminating and also retrieve data from a XML feed.  Problem I am having is it runs the whole event before starting the animating of the loader, so the loader never spins before the data is retrieved.  How can I start the loader's animation and then once it has started continue with getting data from the XML feed?

```
-(IBAction)getXMLData {
    [loader startAnimating];

    [self retrieveXML];
}
. 
. code
. more code
.
-(void)retrieveXMLEnded {
   [loader stopAnimating];
}
```

Comment: If the transaction is fast enough, why would you want to make it slower just to show the wait indicator? It will automatically work when the transaction is slower.

Comment: Because it is making a call to a web server, and sometimes on a 3G connection it is delayed and the user just sits there.  I don't mind a second or two delay to inform the user that something is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strart animation in other thread

```
[loader performSelectorInBackground: @selector(startAnimating) withObject: nil];
```

Comment: Thank You! I used [self.view performSelectorInBackground: @selector(addSubview:) withObject: ActivityBuildingView]; to display a custom loading screen.